# Pointer Events method of checking left- or right-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, pointer-events

I've configured Pointer Events through 
[pointerevents-polyfill](https://github.com/components/pointerevents-polyfill).

There's an issue I have where I cannot differentiate between left- and right-clicks where right-clicking a nav item will do the same action as left-clicking instead of opening the right-click menu.

The specific event I'm using is pointerup.

Is there a way with Pointer Events to check if the event is a left- or right-click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used event.type == 'click' (left) vs. event.type == 'contextmenu' (right).

Answer (score 7):

Looks like there is a property called button that has a value of 0 if it's the primary pointer (left mouse button).

I haven't used this library but from looking at the source and the [W3C spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/pointerevents/raw-file/tip/pointerEvents.html#button-states) it would appear that way.

You can always print/debug the event and see what the property is.

Answer (score 3):

The following code identifies “main button” type pointer events like left mouse click, touch.

```
if(e.pointerType !== 'mouse' || e.button === 0){
    //Not mouse pointer or mouse pointer with left button
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

- 0: Main button pressed, usually the left button or the un-initialized state
- 1: Auxiliary button pressed, usually the wheel button or the middle button (if present)
- 2: Secondary button pressed, usually the right button
- 3: Fourth button, typically the Browser Back button
- 4: Fifth button, typically the Browser Forward button

Comment: Why `button === 0`?

Comment: Please provide more supporting information to your answer.